# Swift making labels disappear when button is clicked

Tags: swift

I would like to make a label disappear and reappear with a click of a button and then reappear with the click of the button again, to reduce clutter on screen.

The following code when it was first run made the button disappear. Which I wanted it to do, but when I closed it off and then ran it again and hit the button the code all of a sudden didn't work meaning that my label didn't disappear. I have not changed any of the code; all I did was run it again.

I am doing this as part of a group project at school. If anyone can help me with my problem that would be great. Thanks.

P.S. `PrepInfo` is the button I'm trying to hide and `PrepButtton` is the button that when pressed, I want to make the `PrepInfo` label disappear.

```
import UIKit

class BackgroundViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBAction func PrepButton(sender: AnyObject) {
        func hide() {
            PrepInfo.hidden = false
        }

        hide()
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var PrepInfo: UILabel!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.

    }


    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */
}
```

Comment: hide() function seems to make hidden _false_ which would mean that it is NOT hidden. It's a bit of funky structure of code that you have the hide function inside PrepButton as well. Just put PrepInfo.hidden = !PrepInfo.hidden in PrepButton.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, if your label is called `myLabel`:

```
// In the code you write to handle button tap

myLabel.hidden = true
```